# TensorflowJS: Failed to parse model.json

Tags: json, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have retrained and converted a Mobilenet model into a model.json-file. This file is loaded into my image classification platform (got a 200 OK status code), but is not recognized as proper json.

I have used these sites to validate my json file

https://jsonlint.com/

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

And both return my file as being validated json.

Two other JSON-files are loaded into the page in the same way, and they return no errors

Yet I still keep getting this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to parse model JSON of response from https://localhost/pathto/model.json. Please make sure the server is serving valid JSON for this request.`

Does anyone know what might be wrong with the file?

EDIT:
I haven't touched the model.json in any way, I simply loaded it into my index.js file and got the error.

Also this my index.js (the full version):

```
  const MODEL_URL =
      "https://localhost/tfjs_models/model.json";
    const WEIGHTS_URL =
      "https://localhost/tfjs_models/weights_manifest.json";
    let model;
    let IMAGENET_CLASSES = [];
    let offset = tf.scalar(128);
    async function loadModelAndClasses() {
  $.getJSON(
    "https://localhost/tfjs_models/labels.json",
    function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        IMAGENET_CLASSES.push(val);
      });
    }
  );
  model = await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);
  //console.log("After model is loaded: " + tf.memory().numTensors);
  $(".loadingDiv").hide();
  $("#inputImage").attr("disabled", false);
}
loadModelAndClasses();
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $("#imageSrc")
        .attr("src", e.target.result)
        .width(224)
        .height(224);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    //console.log("After image is loaded: " + tf.memory().numTensors);

    reader.onloadend = async function() {
      console.log("Before predictions: " + tf.memory().numTensors);

      let imageData = document.getElementById("imageSrc");

      //console.log("After offset: " + tf.memory().numTensors);
      let pixels1 = tf.fromPixels(imageData);
      let pixel2 = pixels1.resizeNearestNeighbor([224, 224]);
      let pixel3 = pixel2.toFloat();
      console.log("After pixels are formed: " + tf.memory().numTensors);

      let pixels = pixel3.sub(offset);
      let pixels4 = pixels.div(offset);
      let pixels5 = pixels4.expandDims();
      console.log("After pre-processing: " + tf.memory().numTensors);

      const output = await model.predict(pixels5);
      console.log("After output: " + tf.memory().numTensors);
      const predictions = Array.from(output.dataSync())
        .map(function(p, i) {
          return {
            probabilty: p,
            classname: IMAGENET_CLASSES[i]
          };
        })
        .sort((a, b) => b.probabilty - a.probabilty)
        .slice(0, 10);

      //console.log(predictions);
      var html = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        html += "<li>" + predictions[i].classname + "</li>";
      }
      $(".predictionList").html(html);
      console.log("After predictions: " + tf.memory().numTensors);

      pixels.dispose();
      pixels1.dispose();
      pixel2.dispose();
      pixel3.dispose();
      pixels4.dispose();
      pixels5.dispose();
      output.dispose();
      console.log("After dispose: " + tf.memory().numTensors);
    };
  }
}
```

This is the link to the model as it was generated by TensorflowJS Converter.

https://github.com/dvbeelen/tfjs_model

Comment: In the code, you're not showing what you're assigning to the variable `model`. What part of the code is throwing the error ?

Comment: You're right, forgot to copy that part, sorry. The error is being thrown by thrown by tfjs at these locations:
 
    at e.<anonymous> (tfjs@1.2.9:2)
    at tfjs@1.2.9:2
    at Object.throw (tfjs@1.2.9:2)
    at s (tfjs@1.2.9:2)

Answer (score 0):

The model is wrongly loaded. Here is the [doc](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#loadGraphModel)

This should be enough to load a model

```
model = await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL)
```

The `weights_manifest.json` needs not to be supplied

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've changed the way my model is loaded, but unfortunately the error remains the same.

Comment: Your python model is a graph model or a layer one ?

Comment: It's a graph model, I followed this tutorial to make it:  https://github.com/woudsma/retrain-mobilenet-for-the-web

Comment: Hi! Was this ever solved? Having the same issue 3 years later :)